# Related to apt-get update command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I am using Ubuntu12.04 and I installed lots of pkg.

I want to update only one specific pkg.

I tried using

```
 $apt-get update pkgname
 E: The update command takes no arguments
```

so then I tried

```
$apt-get update
```

all pkg updated successfully.

Is there any another command to update only one specific pkg?

Comment: try `apt-get install pkgname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get update` does not update a package, it updates the package database. And like user1146332 said using `install` the package automatically updates it too as it fetches the lates version of it.

**PS:** You *have* to do an `update` first to assure you know what the latest versions of the packages actually are.

Comment: It only fetches the latest version from the configured repositories and only if not told otherwise via pinning.

Comment: I doubt it's the case here, I guess it's the default `apt.conf`

Answer (score 1):

vitiv said it correct, either you

```
apt-get install package name
```

to update it to newest version, or you could try

```
apt-get upgrade package name
```

to get the newest version of concerned package

Comment: Next time use shift and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned:

```
apt-get update     # Updates your package lists.

apt-get upgrade    # Upgrades all your packages

apt-get upgrade YOURPACKAGE    # Upgrades only your package (plus dependencies)
```

The advantage of `upgrade` is that it won't mark your package as manually installed.  Thus if you upgrade a package that is only installed *automatically* as a dependency, it will become autoremovable with

```
apt-get autoremove
```

if you deinstall its dependent later on.